# on_member_join not working even with intents

Tags: discord.py

I'm working on making a bot for my server and I want it to automatically assign a role to members that just join. I was looking around on google for an answer and it said to use intents. I used them and even messed around in the dev portal but it's still not working.

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get

bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
Default_Role = 'Starineer'

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name=Default_Role)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

(If I change bot = discord.Client(intents=intents) to client = discord.Client(intents=intents) the commands I have wont work)

Comment: Why do you use `discord.Client` AND `commands.bot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** define `bot` two times. Please decide what you want to use.

Secondly you have to get the role through `discord.utils.get`, just passing the name will not work.

**Here is an example:**

```py
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YourPrefix", intents=intents)

@client.event / @bot.event # Depends on how you defined it
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Test") # Get the role (ID works too)
    await member.add_roles(role) # Add the role
    print(f"{role} assigned to {member}!")
```

*Remember to also import the intents into your code, not just activate them. If you did it like in the example you will be fine.*

***What we did:***

- Get the role through the name or ID -> `name="Test"`/`id=RoleID`
- Imported `discord.utils.get` to be able to get the role.
- Printed out the result to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now